Excel Process Not Ending After Editing & Saving as New
I created a page that will get battalions and open an excel template, write data to fields, save the template as a new file and close the new file.
The code works well except an instance of Excel stays open and I cannot kill the instance. I have tried the codes from different answers here and they have helped but now one process stays running and I want to kill it after the operations.
This is an asp.net 4.5 webforms page and using vb for the language.
The code uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to perform functions.
I just need the Excel process to stop.
here's the code
`        Dim yr As Integer = Today.Year
        Dim mnth As Integer = Today.Month
        Dim ndate As Date = mnth & "/1/" & yr
        Dim lstdate As Date = LastDayOfMont(ndate)
        ndate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, ndate)
        mnth = Month(ndate)
        yr = Year(ndate)
        LblTitle.Text = MonthName(mnth) & "-" & yr
        Dim dtbatallions As DataTable = GetData("Select distinct battalion_id from 
          _app_locations where battalion_id=3 order by battalion_id")

        'Lets start with unsigned logs report
        Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
        Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim sfile As String = 
        Server.MapPath("~/reports/bn_cs_reports/drug_actions_template.xlsx")
        objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sfile)
        For Each r As DataRow In dtbatallions.Rows
            'Lets get the batallions for the report
            Dim dt As DataTable = Getbnunsignedlogs(ndate.ToShortDateString, 
            lstdate.ToShortDateString, r(0).ToString)
            'returns - location_id, location, missed_count
            'Writes the current batallion to the appropriate cell in the Template.
            objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 3).Value = r(0).ToString
            'writes the current Month-yr to the appropriate cell
            objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 6).value = MonthName(mnth) & "-" & yr

            'Preparing the name of the new file that the Template with the new information 
            will be saved to.
            Dim fname As String = Server.MapPath("~/reports/bn_cs_reports/bn/" & 
            LblTitle.Text.Trim.ToUpper() & "/bn-" & r(0).ToString.Trim & ".xlsx")
            Dim m As Integer = 0
            'create directory if it doesn't exist.
            Dim pth As String = Server.MapPath("~/reports/bn_cs_reports/bn/" & 
             LblTitle.Text.Trim.ToUpper() & "/")
            If Directory.Exists(pth) = False Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pth)
            End If

            Do While IO.File.Exists(fname)
                m = m + 1
                fname = Server.MapPath("~/reports/bn_cs_reports/bn/" & 
            LblTitle.Text.Trim.ToUpper() & "/bn-" & r(0).ToString.Trim & "(" & m & ").xlsx")
            Loop
            Dim dbfname As String = "~/reports/bn_cs_reports/bn/" & LblTitle.Text.Trim.ToUpper() & "/bn-" & r(0).ToString.Trim & ".xlsx"
            If m > 0 Then dbfname = "~/reports/bn_cs_reports/bn/" & LblTitle.Text.Trim.ToUpper() & "/bn-" & r(0).ToString.Trim & "(" & m & ").xlsx"
            objWorkbook.SaveAs(fname)
            objWorkbook.Close(fname)
        Next
        objExcel.Workbooks.Close()
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objWorkbook)

        objExcel.Quit()
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objExcel)


        'All works but an instance of Excel is still running in processes (Task Manager).
`

Need your help!
